# What is the diffrence between MVA and ASP.NET web form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the diffrence between MVA and ASP.NET web form?

Answer (score 1):

As your question is tagged with "asp.net-mvc" I will answer the following question...

> What is the difference between MVC and
>   ASP.NET web forms?

**State**

I'm mentioning this one because I think it is one of the most important differences, a full list is provided in the link below.

An ASP.NET web form is stateful, it remembers stuff for you between "post backs". It makes the internet behave a little bit like a windows forms application. This is great if you are a forms developer moving into web development, but it breaks the natural behaviour of web pages.

ASP.NET MVC applications are stateless. They don't remember anything between pages. This is how web pages are supposed to work - each request should supply the required information for any action to be taken, all using the standard HTTP verbs as detailed here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

**The Lowdown**

Dino Esportivo has written a really detailed article on all of the subtle differences here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links and find your answer [Biggest Advantage to use asp.net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms) and

[Advantages and disadvantages to use asp.net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674102/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-asp-net-webforms-vs-asp-net-mvc-some-points) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552984/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-forms/1553089#1553089)
there are lots of discussion on such question you may call them debate also
thanks