# MVC VS web pages

Tags: model-view-controller

I planning to start a new web application, can any one explain me which one will be best to start, Old Web Forms method or MVC Application.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this previous answer which highlights advantages of both

[ASP.NET vs Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552984/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-forms)