# ASP.NET MVC Experiences/Success Stories [2010]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

At the moment we're evaluating whether it's worth it to start using ASP.NET MVC in combination with Visual Studio 2010.

I've been searching the web for experiences developers have had with working with ASP.NET MVC. I can't seem to find any. So I decided to post a question here.

Are there any people out there that have used ASP.NET-MVC for serious development? What are the experiences so far? Does ASP.NET-MVC help or hinder projects? Do you deliver your project on time? Does ASP.NET-MVC save you time or does it make you go over time and over budget?

And then the big question: Now that you've been working with ASP.NET MVC for a while, do you wish you had chosen an alternative? If that's the case, which alternative?

Thanks,

M

Comment: It's a very good question. Right now I'm in the middle of a project builded in MVC... sometimes we have some trobles, but mostly because of ASP.NET AJAX habits and non-mvc way of thinking. 

Generaly it's very good and easy, the work is going exacly with a schedule and we dont have any blocking problems, but as I say we are just in a half way.

Comment: We use it for business-level applications.  It's simply an alternative to WebForms, it's neither better nor worse (although the majority seem biased on that viewpoint).  I _prefer_ it because there's a clear distinction between concerns, whereas WebForms seemed to mash things together dangerously, promoting bad design and making it more difficult to maintain the web application.  I also find it easier.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms Also, the phrasing "Are there any people out there that have used ASP.NET-MVC for *serious* development" is so biassed that it feels pointless to answer your question. ;]

Comment: Oh. I didn't mean it as an offence. I should have said: "Do you consider ASP.NET-MVC mature enough to be intregrated into critical systems and be an essential part of your workflow?". That's basically my definition of "serious".

Comment: C'mon... Your asking for things that can't be answered without knowing exactly what type of team you have.  "What are the experiences so far? Does ASP.NET-MVC help or hinder projects?"  Do you have flexible developers that have interest in learning new things?  Are they comfortable with HTML/CSS/AJAX/Javascript?  Are they in love with WebForms?  Do you have code reviews and shared learning time?  

Any new stack is going to take time to learn.  Your assuming everybody is on the same page here.

Comment: @jfar Yes we have flexible developers that are very interested in learning news things. Yes they are comfortable in with HTML/CSS/AJAX/JavaScript (We use Dojo very extensively). I hate webforms, but the other developers have no experience outside of using Webforms. No we don't have code reviews of shared learning time. Yes any new stack is going to take time to learn, but my question is: is it worth it? Yes I'm assuming everybody is on the same page.

Comment: @mghaoui, now your starting to ask a different question...  I mean even your comment.  What is "worth it" mean to you?  Saves time?  Easier to develop in?  Faster?

Comment: @jfar Ok ... maybe I should have put more thought into the formulation of this question. I thought I was being pretty obvious. I'm going to go back to the drawing board ...

Comment: This is my experience: If you hate web forms (like me) then it's worth learning MVC (if you can convince other people who work with you to use it (I did ;)).

Comment: @mghaoui I would say that for many scenarios, ASP.NET MVC is *more* mature than ASP.NET Web Forms. For example, the ability to unit test cover your entire web application, and the ability to use Test Driven Design to create it, are two things that I've seen - on real, commercial projects - improve stability, reliability and quality *enormously*. Ever seen a huge code-behind Web Form file that nobody knows quite what it does and is impossible to unit test? Did you think it was mature? :) For me, ASP.NET MVC has also cut development time *drastically* over Web Forms when it was the right choice.

Answer (score 5):

StackOverflow itself is an ASP.NET MVC site and I would say it is pretty successful.

I think it depends more on the people doing the actual implementation of the site than on the technology used how 'successful' the end result will be (successful in the broadest sense: on time, within budget, happy end users, ...).

Comment: Yeah I know. Are there any sites out there besides StackOverflow that are pretty succesful?

Comment: @mghaoui That question isn't going to get a lot of answers. Nobody likes to boast, and many users here prefer their semi-anonymity and wouldn't come out as authors of specific sites. Just saying. :)

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net mvc is a better then asp.net webform some reason are here

the logic code in asp.net MVC is maintainable and clean.

he provide a better performance then webform

provide a pretty url for SEO and user-friendly.

full control on mockup [without using server-side control].

if you want to see there are many example of MVC project. stackoverflow.com is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of ASP.NET MVC (especially with the great improvements done in MVC3). I have worked on two big sites built entirely in MVC2 [SempToshiba Brazil](http://loja.semptoshiba.com.br/home/index) and [Cyrela Brasil](http://www.cyrela.com). These projects have been quite sucessful. They were delivered on time, saved time and our clients were very happy. Lastly, no, I would not have chosen an alternative. A side note, the Cyrela project was actually a re-do of a ASP.NET Web Forms site that had various downsides.

On the other hand, I have seen a large project done in MVC 2 by inexperience programmers, and it is one the worse projects I have ever seen. So, over all, ASP.NET MVC has some major advantages, but if the team is inexperienced in ASP.NET MVC you will get poor results.

On another note, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056771/learning-materials-for-asp-net-mvc-3-0-please-list) has some great ASP.NET MVC 3 material.