# Learning Materials for ASP.NET MVC 3.0? Please list!

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for learning materials (like blog posts and tutorials) for ASP.NET MVC 3.0 specific materials.

If you know of any books, blogs, sites or online resources that are exclusively, predominently or even mainly MVC 3.0 related, I would love to hear about them, also, specific links to individual MVC 3.0 related tutorials & blog posts would also be accepted if you were so inclined.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you looking for samples/tutorials that only demonstrate the new features in ASP.NET MVC 3.0, or tutorials that involve ASP.NET MVC and touch on 3.0 to an extent?  Having been out for less than a month with less than 1300 downloads, you may not find much.

Comment: @Jim, anything that is MVC 3.0 specific really. I must say, are the downloads count really that low? 1,300? Is that just the Beta release or the Preview 1 and Beta combined? Where did you get this stat?

Comment: It's the only release I see for ASP.NET MVC 3: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/54306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's Channel9 site has quite a few MVC 3 focused videos here: [mvcConf](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf)

The videos aren't necessarily beginner level but they cover a range of useful topics like deployment, integrating jQuery and improving performance, among others.

Also, check out [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-3.productCd-1118076583.html) by Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Brad Wilson, K. Scott Allen

Comment: I gotta say, those video resources were a great find. I think there are other yearly talks/seminars where MVC videos are uploaded and made public, but I forget their names (usually live sessions but recordings uploaded after weekend or week ends). If you remember any of them, feel free to update answer or list. Thanks. Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 8):

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx
- http://haacked.com/tags/aspnetmvc/default.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes
- http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/aspnet_mvc/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/tags/asp-net+mvc/

Answer (score 5):

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, Third Edition](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430234043) by steve sanderson

Comment: This is gold, thank you, had no idea he was already working on version 3 since vie got both 1 and 2 :)

Comment: YOu can be sure he is :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently went to one of the asp.net MVC3 web camps in Redmond, WA. You can access all their presentation slides , demos and labs here. I found it pretty useful as an introduction to MVC3. There are beginner and intermediate labs. Hope this helps!
http://trainingkit.webcamps.ms/AspNetMvc.htm

Of course, as they are free, you can check the schedule to see if there might be one near you. Especially useful for beginners and if you have specific questions, they had a lot of their team on hand to answer questions.