# ASP .NET or MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms)

Which would you pick if developing a new application?

Comment: The same answer as always **it depends**

Answer (score 4):

MVC is a framework that sits on top of ASP.NET. What you should be asking is should you use Webforms VS MVC. Watch some of the getting started videos at http://www.asp.net/mvc and see which one you like more. You will need some VB or C# experience, so learn one of those first. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

MVC3 because it gives you everything ASP.NET gives you... plus a WHOLE LOT MORE.  Also, MVC3 does not prevent you from using ASP.NET.