# What is the best approach to start the following project in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I am new to ASP.NET Web Forms. Now I am having a small project that I have develop it in ASP.NET. This project consists of the following:
1. data entry system: adding, editing and deleting users
2. defining two roles of the users: admin or registered user
3. creating, editing and deleting events
4. creating simple reports with some graphs

I am expert with HTML, CSS and Javascript. Also, I have a good background in C# and I used Oracle database during my university life, so I know SQL language.

I finished the Lynda Essential Training about ASP.NET and now I am thinking to start my project but I am confused about my start and I don't know from where I should start.

In addition, I have the following questions:
1. Should I know Entity Framework and know how to use it and use it in my project? Is is possible to develop the website with the SqlDataSource?

1. what is the best and short approach to develop this website from your experience?
2. Do I need to take another tutorial or is it fine to start with project and taking specific tutorial for each problem that I will face?

Your help guys is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There were a few decisions to make:

### Project Type

**Web Project** or **Web Application Project**

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

### Pattern

**MVC** or classic **Web Forms**

See [Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms)

### Data Access

**Entity Framework** (currently in BETA for use with Oracle, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html), **LINQ to SQL**, **System.Data.SqlClient** classes