# ASP.Net MVC or Web forms which is better

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am going to start work on a SaaS based application. I need to decide whether to go with ASP.Net MVC or web forms application. Through various posts I came to know that both are good, they are not replacement of each other and so on.

Also, I know traditional web forms method, I am not aware of MVC, I need to learn it first.

Please guide me which approach is better.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Pls check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right answer here. I prefer MVC but if you already know ASP.Net WebForms it probably is easier to stick with that.

Comment: Thanks Chris . I am just concerned about the learning time over the project delivery. Do you have any links to compare the benefits or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

i can just share some of my experience as i have worked on both
i preffer asp.net MVC over Asp.net because 
of the futile layer of abstraction that Asp.Net has over basic HTTP architecture
the user controls in asp.Net induce unnecessary markup
ease of using `ajax` in asp.net mvc compared to `updatepanel`(in advanced senarious)
support of razor type syntax increases productivity
no overloading by things like `viewstate`

because everything is managed by the programmer soem of the typical issues that arise in asp.net like the problems in dynamic controls are no longer present

so if you ask me go for `asp.net MVC`

Comment: +1 This is a good summary of the benefits of MVC over webforms.