# asp.net webforms vs asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am window form guy and now have to deploy some web application. I am still consifering either choose mvc or webforms. I am not very familar wit html/css/ajax staff. SOmehow i heard mvc is a "new way to go" but i am a bit worry about time to learn all this stuff and just go with standard webforms to use my controls which are available inside toolbox also with devexpress controls. I am wonder if mvc doesnt have controls drag-drop available how to handle such things like grid to populate from database and other staff? How mvc developers handling with it without controls? Can you advice me a bit? I hear something that ajax could provide me with controls.

Comment: ASP.NET is more natural for a Windows-Forms developer because it's controls-based

Comment: if i would choose asp.net mvc how i could handle with such controls like grid, button if they are not inside toolbox anymore? What mvc can offer in this case?

Comment: Read about [HtmlHelpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Here is a post on MVC vs. WebForms, favouring MVC :)

Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms