# Is the asp.net-mvc instead way of regular asp.net web froms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about MVC,

Can we say that mvc is the instead way of regular asp.net web froms?

If not **which scenario that I should not use MVC pattern?**

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: As with all things, it depends on what you want to do. ASP.NET is good for certain scenarios, ASP.NET MVC is good for others. I have tried both, and for many reasons I prefer MVC, but YMMV. Offhand, I can't think of a good instance where you should *not* use MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes MVC is alternate to webform. The scenario in which you should not use asp.net mvc is when you don't have solid oop concepts. you can read more from [this](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/you-should-not-use-asp.net-mvc-if/)  blog post

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Asp.Net MVC is an alternative to Webforms for websites.

Answer (score 0):

see

- [Should you use asp net mvc](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2009/04/21/should-you-use-asp-net-mvc/)
- [Deciding when use aspnet mvc](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/deciding-when-use-aspnet-mvc-f)
- [When to use asp net mvc vs asp net web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144153/when-to-use-asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-web-forms)